# How to divide the tables that have only one value in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

```
DUMP avg_2000       
DUMP avg_2001      
DUMP avg_2002
```

OUTPUT : 1345.45    OUTPUT : 1256.45   OUTPUT : 1456.45

Please guide me how to divide avg_2000/avg_2002 in PIG

Comment: can u post your script?

Answer (score 0):

Access the first field in both relations using the Postional Notation.
$0 will give you the first field in the relation

```
avg_2000.$0/avg_2002.$0
```